# Convert xy spatial points into spatial lines

Tags: r, sp, rgeos

I have produced a SpatialPoints object (named `v3`) in R from the function `gIntersection` (package `rgeos`). The SpatialPoints object `v3` has the following structure and is represented by red points on the image below.

```
    > summary(v3)
    Object of class SpatialPoints
    Coordinates:
            min       max
    x  310440.5  310680.5
    y 4996427.5 4997297.5
    Is projected: TRUE 
    proj4string :
    [+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-73.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=304800 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    +units=m +no_defs]
    Number of points: 32
```

[image]

From the SpatialPoints object `v3`, how can I convert the red points into 3 spatial lines as in the image below ?

[image]

The SpatialPoints object `v3` has only spatial coordinates x and y.

**Update**

I used the function `gIntersection` with two objects of class `spatialPolygons` (squares in the images) and I almost get the desired result (i.e., to draw boundaries between polygons that have different values). But the function  `gIntersection` creates a object of class `SpatialCollections` with `1 feature`. So, How can I convert objects of class `SpatialCollections` into objects of class `SpatialLines` ? From the reproducible example, I would like to get only the lines in red (and not the points).

Here the reproducible example:

```
r <- raster(ncols=90, nrows=50, resolution = 30)
projection(r) <- CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-73.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=304800 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs")
values(r) <- sample(1:3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
plot(r)

p1 <- rasterToPolygons(r, fun=function(x){x==1})
plot(p1,add=T)
p1 <- as(p1,"SpatialPolygons")

p2 <- rasterToPolygons(r, fun=function(x){x==3})
plot(p2,add=T)
p2 <- as(p2,"SpatialPolygons")

p3 <- gIntersection(p1,p2,byid=T)
plot(p3,add=T,col="red",lwd=3)
> p3
class       : SpatialCollections 
features    : 1 
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-73.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=304800 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than this images you should provide some data. You can make `SpatialLines` with `spLines` in `raster`

```
library(raster)
?spLines
```

But the points need to be ordered correctly, and if they are not, it may be difficult to get them in the right order.

To get a `SpatialLines` object from your `SpatialCollection` do

```
x <- p3@lineobj
plot(x,add=T,col="blue",lwd=3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much RobertH for your help. I added a reproducible   example.

Comment: and I added a response to that